# How to setup "Cancel Order" option to a customer in customer's My Account section?

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to allow customers to cancel their pending orders in "My Account" section.

I tried this [tutorial](http://en.herveguetin.com/allow-customers-to-cancel-their-orders.html#.Uuti5XDPUa5), but it doesn't show 'cancel order' link in customer "My Orders" page.

How can I do this in Magento ?

Any assistance will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you know how to create the method in controller and how to access that method on front-end.

Create the simple link in my account page and create the method in your controller and and  write the below code in your method that order Status Will be changed.

```
$orderId = YOUR_ORDER_ID;
$order = Mage::getModel(‘sales/order’)
 ->load($orderId);

$order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true)->save();
```

Comment: I didn't getting you what you said.

Comment: I meant, I created "cancel order" section for customers using your code.

Comment: hmm that's grate

Comment: wouldn't this allow the user to edit the URL to contain a different order ID though? Assuming you're using url params? Meaning a user can cancel other peoples orders via the url

Answer (score 0):

I realise that it is generally frowned upon to simply recommend an extension as a solution, but the following extension is free and I have been using it on 1.7.0.2 without any problems (despite it being listed as only compatible with 1.4 and 1.5)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/order-cancel-link.html

Comment: Yes I tried this extension also. But I have not seen any link to cancel order in "Order History" Page.